# Iterate through resource string table

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a string table defined like this in my Win32 app:

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_STRING101           "myString1"
    IDS_STRING102           "myString2"
    IDS_STRING103           "myString3"
END
```

Since I want all of these strings to be part of an array, is it possible to iterate through this table? Since `LoadStringA()` requires the macros IDS_STRING101 etc., it seems impossible to iterate through it.

For a practical example, how would I programatically move these strings to an array of strings (`char*` array in C, `std::string` array in C++) without using the obvious way of writing a long repetitive code of `LoadStringA()` calls with the second parameter `IDS_STRINGXXX`? If possible, I want to be able to add more strings to this table in the future without modifying anything in the code.

Comment: Not sure, what you are really trying to accomplish here. But nothing keeps you from defining symbolic constants like `IDS_STRING_FIRST` and `IDS_STRING_LAST` in your resource.h file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was thinking about creating a loop for `LoadString()`, but how should I know which string to read in the loop? Is it possible to iterate through the constants? (From what I read I have to pass `IDS_STRINGXXX` to `LoadString()`)

Comment: `LoadString` expects a numeric value. Adding `1` to a number is trivial.

Comment: It is whatever you assigned to `IDS_STRING101`. The value is stored in resource.h by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RemyLebeau this is what I needed. Seems like am extremely dumb. That was easy enough.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Doesn't that assume that the constants are consecutive?

Comment: @edw That's not an assumption. It's a requirement. A requirement that can easily be arranged for.

Comment: @EdwardKarak ...and if one wants to load non-consecutive strings one could replace the loop with `for(UINT id : {IDS_STRING101,IDS_STRING102,IDS_STRING103}) {
        LoadString(...,id,...);    
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API to enumerate through the individual strings of a string table. You would have to load the entire string table resource as a whole into memory and then parse it manually per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/stringtable-resource).

A simpler solution would be to just call `LoadStringA()` in a loop, since your string IDs are sequential, eg:

```
char myStrings[3][16] = {};
for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; ++idx) {
    LoadStringA(hInstance, IDS_STRING101 + idx, myStrings[idx], 16);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> how would I programatically move these strings to an array of strings

You could hide the tedious repetitions in a function or class.

Class example:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class StringLoader {
public:
    StringLoader(HINSTANCE inst) : hInstance(inst) {}

    std::pair<UINT,std::string> operator()(UINT uID) {
        const char* resptr;
        UINT len = LoadStringA(hInstance, uID, reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&resptr), 0);
        if(len==0) throw std::runtime_error("resource not found: "+std::to_string(uID));
        return {uID, {resptr, resptr+len}};
    }
private:
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
};

//... then use it:

    StringLoader l(the_instance);
    std::unordered_map<UINT, std::string> resources {
        l(IDS_STRING101),
        l(IDS_STRING102),
        l(IDS_STRING103)
    };
```

You'll now have a map that you can iterate over, or use as a lookup table. If you only need the strings, you can replace the map with a `vector` and adjust `StringLoader` accordingly.